# RegEx: Match until specified word

Tags: regex, vba, vbscript

I want to match following sentences:

```
<b>(ABC)</b>
<b> (ABC) </b>
<b> abc (ABC) fgt </b>
```

Pattern is following:

```
"(<b>.*?\()([A-Z]+)(\).*?</b>)"
```

This works fine for examples above, but if sentence is following:

```
<b></b>(ABCA)<b>(ABCB)</b>
```

Then I get wrong match. Regex finds first occurrence of `<b>` and matches until first `(`. Next it skips all words until `</b>`. That's wrong. Correct match must be `<b>(ABCB)</b>`. How to fix that?

Comment: what would be the expected output for the above string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep a regex from crossing tag boundaries, the `.*` "match anything" token is too loose an approach because "anything" also covers the tags themselves.

You can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that `<b>` and `</b>` can't be part of the match:

```
(<b>(?:(?!</?b>).)*\()([A-Z]+)(\)(?:(?!</?b>).)*</b>)
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/kG1cW9/1).

**Explanation:**

```
(         # Match into group 1:
 <b>      # <b>
 (?:      # Start of non-capturing group
  (?!     # Match only if it's impossible to match
    </?b> # <b> or </b>
  )       # (End of lookahead assertion)
  .       # Match any character
 )*       # Repeat as many times as possible
 \(       # Then match a (
)         # End of group 1
([A-Z]+)  # Match one or more uppercase ASCII letters --> group 2
(         # Match into group 3:
 \)       # Match )
 (?:(?!</?b>).)* # as before, match anything except <b> or </b>
 </b>     # Match </b>
)         # End of group 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.*?` with `[^<>]*` in your regex, so that it would match any char but not of `<` or `>` zero or more times. This ensures that there is no tag present inbetween the opening and closing `<b>` tags.

```
(<b>[^<>]*?\()([A-Z]+)(\)[^<>]*?</b>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vF9jV6/8)

Comment: +1, although of course that prevents *any* tags from occurring between `<b>` and `</b>`, which should be enough unless something like `<b><i>(ABCD)</i></b>` could happen. And you don't really need to keep the lazy quantifiers, I think.

Comment: Yep, if the input contains `<b><i>(ABCD)</i></b>`, then mine won't work.